# Error: Compile Error: expecting a right parentheses, found '&' at line 13 column 0

Tags: trigger

here I just want to check whether my assignment rule is working properly or not, so I have written a trigger, but in trigger I think I am doing something wrong so getting this error--Error: Compile Error: expecting a right parentheses, found '&' at line 13 column 0
, can anyone please help me out.

```
trigger Testing on Case (after insert) {

List<Profile> PROFILE = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile WHERE Id=:userinfo.getProfileId() LIMIT 1];
Public String MyProflieName = PROFILE[0].Name;
List<User> Use = new List<User>([SELECT Phone, Id FROM User WHERE Id = : UserInfo.getUserId()]);
for(Case c:Trigger.New)
    {
        for(User u: Use)
        {
            System.Debug(
            (c.RecordType.Name='Client Service')
            &((c.Categories__c !='DCS Client Services')||(c.Categories__c !='DCS Technical Support'))
            &((c.Account_Segmentation__c != 'Z2')||(c.Account_Segmentation__c != 'Z3')||(c.Account_Segmentation__c != 'Z4')||(c.Account_Segmentation__c !=' Z5')||(c.Account_Segmentation__c != 'D1'))
            &((MyProflieName=='DCS Client Services')||(MyProflieName=='DCS Technical Support'))
            &((c.Origin='Email')||(c.Origin='Phone')||(c.Origin='Chat')||(c.Origin='Internal'))
            &(!((u.FirstName='PBI')&(u.LastName='Default')))
            );

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are sure you want to use bitwise AND operator? Can you try with `&&`?

Comment: Just make your & as && instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use && instead of & for joining two logical conditions.
So, your code should look like something this:

```
List<Profile> PROFILE = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile WHERE Id=:userinfo.getProfileId() LIMIT 1];
Public String MyProflieName = PROFILE[0].Name;
List<User> Use = new List<User>([SELECT Phone, Id FROM User WHERE Id = : UserInfo.getUserId()]);
for(Case c:Trigger.New)
    {
        for(User u: Use)
        {
            System.Debug(
            (c.RecordType.Name='Client Service')
            &&((c.Categories__c !='DCS Client Services')||(c.Categories__c !='DCS Technical Support'))
            &&((c.Account_Segmentation__c != 'Z2')||(c.Account_Segmentation__c != 'Z3')||(c.Account_Segmentation__c != 'Z4')||(c.Account_Segmentation__c !=' Z5')||(c.Account_Segmentation__c != 'D1'))
            &&((MyProflieName=='DCS Client Services')||(MyProflieName=='DCS Technical Support'))
            &&((c.Origin='Email')||(c.Origin='Phone')||(c.Origin='Chat')||(c.Origin='Internal'))
            &&(!((u.FirstName='PBI')&&(u.LastName='Default')))
            );

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Last part of debug : &&(!((u.FirstName='PBI') **&&** (u.LastName='Default'))